# Memory leaks in my application

Tags: objective-c, ios4, memory-leaks

i am working on an IOS application.In Xcode I'd analyze the application Run->analyze
It showed 47 potential memory leaks I checked out all the cases in most of the cases it is not possible to dealloc the memory,will there be any problem while launching the application in appstore?
I have thoroughly checked the application it is not crashing anywhere neither it is showing low memory warning anywhere.
As i am new in IOS development kindly suggest me what i can do about this

Will it be enough to dealloc the memory in viewDidUnload method to avoid memory leaks?

Comment: Just use ARC. I have never run into a memory leak while using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may not be rejected if it doesnt show any memory warnings. But building apps with leaks is generally not good programming. Why arent you solving those leaks? There is not a single situation where you wont be able to release your allocations. Use autorelease or pass the release message to the elements wherever needed.

Also, for better analysis of your app, run the app with INSTRUMENTS, it'll give you a better idea where the leaks are coming from.

EDIT : How to run app with Instruments.

When you are in Xcode, Click on Run in the Top Menu Bar. In this section, go into the **Run with Performance Tools** and then select **Leaks**.

To know, how to use Instruments, go [here](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/04/02/cocoa-tutorial-fixing-memory-leaks-with-instruments/).

Comment: Can you tell me how to run app with INSTRUMENTS

Answer (score 2):

*Note : I have not had an opportunity to play with some of the newest features like ARC so this may or may not be out of date now.*

Yes this could be an issue. According to Apple, this is one thing that they do check for.  Nothing seems to guarantee rejection (or acceptance) by apple's review team, however.  Perhaps more importantly, however, you want your reputation as an app developer to be good, you want to be in the business of making people's phones work *better* for them.

Done right, you will always be to release any objects you have created with new or alloc.

However to prevent, track down and eliminate memory leaks you need to use :
     1. analysis
     2. Instruments Leaks
     3. Your own analysis, and peer review when needed
     4. Clean coding, best practices and patterns

While using Instruments Leaks profiling tool, use your app and try to hit all the different execution paths.  See if objects appear as being leaked.  I usually prioritize by total size of leak (object size * number of leaks), then work my way down until no leaks are showing up.  Clicking on the object will show you somewhere near where the object originally gets allocated.

I found that even Instruments might not catch all of the memory leaks explicitly.

One more trick, that might help in this regard, is to reason out some different "loops" you can make in your app where, once you return "home" your app should have the same memory footprint as the last time you were there. For example, start at the home screen, carries out activity X, then activity Y, then return to the home screen.  Lets say that you expect, after the first cycle, the 2nd and 3rd time you get back to the home screen, the memory foot print should be the same. You can then practice this with Instruments connected and the number of *allocations*.  This can give you some valuable information.

There are some interesting things that can happen with retention cycles, which can happen when you have a circular dependency between classes, and is easy to have happen when trying to do certain things with blocks.

You might be tempted to ignore a warning about a memory leak, when the object persists for the lifetime of the app (like a singleton).  My opinion is to eliminate the warnings and deallocate the object somewhere, as a matter of cleanliness.

You will also feel very good about having zero compiler and zero analyser warnings when you build!

Answer (score 1):

If you're testing on the simulator, chances are you'd never see a low memory warning anyway.  But regardless, all memory leaks should be fixable except those which exist in Apple frameworks (of which there likely aren't many).

What kind of information is being returned by Analyze?